# where to find a number of subdomain in bluehost

Tags: wordpress

i used wordpress CMS and i want to show 5 recent post from subdomain to show on main site, the solution i found is

```
 <?php
    global $switched;
    switch_to_blog(7);
    echo 'You switched from blog ' . $switched . ' to 7';
    restore_current_blog();
    echo 'You switched back.';
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
switch_to_blog( 2 ); // Switch to the blog that you want to pull posts from. You can see the ID when you edit a site through the Network Admin - the URL will look something like "http://example.com/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=2" - you need the value of "id", in this case "2" ?>

<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>

<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>

<?php restore_current_blog(); // Restore the current blog ?>
```

but id don't know where to find the number of subdomain..where to find it.. please help

Comment: This question is very unclear. What does bluehost have to do with it??  I don't see anything about a subdomain.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As a first question, this is lacking (and a candidate for closure). The critique is that you can do more research of your own. Appropriate time for a post is when research cannot take you any further, you already have fairly well implemented features.

Answer (score 0):

Bluehost sub-domains aren't exactly easy to identify even if you use PHP to crawl the folders that subdomains are in.

Your best bet is to have a text file accessible to all scripts that lists the subdomains. Read that file in and work with it.